# How can I utilize Postman to monitor an excel file within my Sharepoint and automatically re-download the file if any changes were made?

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, postman

Currently I have my GET set to download this excel file from my Sharepoint but I need to send this GET request manually each time I want to download the file. How can I set up Postman to automatically download this file whenever the file is updated in Sharepoint? I saw you could use runs to set scheduled GET requests but for some reason I don't have that tab plus I need this downloaded when the file is updated, rather than a daily call.

[image]

(Attempted step from what I've researched is above. Couldn't find any documentation on automatically downloading Sharepoint files when they're modified)